# Making an after bracha before leaving your place

Tags: sources-mekorot, blessing, bentching

Where does it say that if one (who is eating alone) wishes to leave in the middle of a seudah (even if they will return after some time -- however before the time that is allowed for them to make an after bracha has passed) they must first make an after bracha (particularly by bircas hamazon, although perhaps other brachas as well?) This has been something that I always heard was the "right" thing to do? Does it have a source?

In a [previous question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65713/saying-birkas-hamazon-after-leaving-your-house) it was discussed what to do if someone did leave and then came back to their seudah if they may continue eating or if they need to make an after bracha first and then a new bracha. My question is where does it say (in poskim) that a person *must* make an after bracha before leaving.

Answer (score 3):

[The R"ma (O.C. 178:2)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.178.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) cites the opinion of Rishonim that one should not leave without saying *bircas hamazon* because he may forget to return and say it later (and the Mishna Brurah s.k. 36 says that many Achronim extend this concern to non-bread meals as well).

[The Mishna Brurah (s.k. 34)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.178.35?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) qualifies this based on Rishonim who imply that if one will return immediately, he need not worry.